# Can not access headers in extended Express.Request type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to extend Express' `Request` to type exactly what a query will look like. I currently do this as follows:

```js
export interface TypedRequestQuery<T> extends Express.Request {
    query: T;
}
```

This works for the most part, but some properties do not seem to be defined. For example:

```js
(req as TypedRequestQuery<{data: string}>).headers
```

Does not work. It results in the following error:

```
Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'TypedRequestQuery<{ data: string; }>'
```

I have read in multiple sources that `Express.Request` is the correct type for a request handler's request argument. But maybe I misunderstood? Leaving out the typings of the request handler does work!:

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] // no errors
})
```

And the `headers` property is present in the `req`.

I am using `passport.js` which I noticed changes the definition of `Request` (or at least extends it). Not sure if this is the cause.

My question is: Is `Express.Request` the correct type to be extending from here? If it is, why does the interface seem incomplete and how can I fix this? If not, what type should I extend from?

Comment: Hello, if I had to do this, I would only type the query property without using an interface extending _Request_. You can use `req.headers`, and then you can do `const query = req.query as T` and use _query_ in the rest of the code.

Comment: Although this would definitely be a workaround. This is definitely something I have considered. But, I would still really like to figure out why exactly my proposed solution is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express' [Request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L380-L386) type already lets you define the query type...

```ts
export interface Request<
    P = ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = ParsedQs, // 
    Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> ...
```

The query type is the 4th generic so you'd need to provide defaults for the first three

```ts
import { ParamsDictionary, Request } from "express-serve-static-core";

type TypedRequestQuery<
  TQuery,
  TParams = ParamsDictionary,
  TResBody = any,
  TReqBody = any
> = Request<TParams, TResBody, TReqBody, TQuery>;
```

Then you can use it in your routes

```ts
router.get("/", async (req: TypedRequestQuery<{data: string}>, res) => {
  console.log("headers[x-forwarded-for]:", req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
  console.log("query[data]:", req.query.data);

  res.send("I wish Typescript would let us skip generics");
})
```

---

Your example fails compilation because you're trying to override the `query` property with an incompatible type

> ```
> error TS2430: Interface 'TypedRequestQuery<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
>   Types of property 'query' are incompatible.
>     Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ParsedQs'.
>
> interface TypedRequestQuery<T> extends Request {
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>     interface TypedRequestQuery<T> extends Request {
>                                 ~
>     This type parameter might need an `extends ParsedQs` constraint.
> ```

A compatible version would need to have your query type extend `ParsedQs`

```ts
import { Request } from "express-serve-static-core";
import { ParsedQs } from "qs"

interface TypedRequestQuery<T extends ParsedQs> extends Request {
  query: T;
}
```

Comment: Aha, I did not realize this! I am still not quite sure why my proposed solution would not work. Would it be possible to give an explanation for this in your answer?

Comment: @BramVanbilsen I actually couldn't get your example to compile... _"This type parameter might need an `extends QueryString.ParsedQs` constraint."_. You cannot overwrite an interface property with an incompatible type

Comment: @BramVanbilsen I've updated my answer with more details