# Is there a way to assign req.body types based on a middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have an express middleware that validates body input using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup). Based on the schema I pass in, I would like to assign the type of the schema to `req.body`.

Is it possible to set the type of `req.body` to the type of `schema` from within the `validates` middleware? I tried using `yup.InferType<typeof schema>` but wasn't sure how to apply it to `req.body`.

Here's the middleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Schema, ValidationError } from 'yup'

export default function validate(schema: Schema) {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const body = await schema.validate(req.body, {
        stripUnknown: true
      })

      // TODO: Is there a way to dynamically type this to the type of the schema?
      req.body = body

      next()
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof ValidationError) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
      }
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Unknown error' })
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a route that utilizes the middleware:

```
import { object, string } from 'yup'

// ...

const schema = object({
  name: string().required()
})

app.put('/test/:id', validate(schema), async (req, res) => {
  // ...

  req.body.name // currently "any" but would like this to be "string" from the schema
  req.body.unknownProperty // this would error as it's not part of the schema
  
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75925156/283366) help? You can set the `TReqBody` type for `Request` directly in your route handlers

Comment: @Philisonstrike it does, thank you. After further investigation, I think I found my problem. I can type the request body manually from the middleware and it'll show up in the route, but the problem seems to be that I'm typing the parameter in the middleware incorrectly. So when I use InferType, it's always `any` because it doesn't know what it's inferring, which makes sense. I was ultimately trying to infer the types to mitigate manually writing them but it may come down to setting the type on the route handler rather than the middleware. Thanks again for the help.